# Method call on page object does not return result

Tags: watir, watir-webdriver, page-object-gem

I am having problem to use page object method call to return an object on the page.

Here is my example codes in test_log_in.rb

```
 ...
    class TestLogIn < Test::Unit::TestCase
    .....
      def test_failed_log_in
        @log_in_page= LogIn.new(@browser)
        @log_in_page.go_to_log_in

        @log_in_page.log_in("174773476","test","aaa111as")

        puts @log_in_page.error_message
        puts @log_in_page.get_error_message
      end

    end
```

My log in class is defined below:

```
class LogIn
  include PageObject

  ...
  h3(:error_message, :class => 'no-margin white-text')

  ...

  def log_in (access_number, user_id, password)
    self.access_number = access_number
    self.user_id = user_id
    self.password = password
    log_me_in
    AccountSummary.new(@browser)
  end

 ....
 def get_error_message
    self.error_message
  end
  ....  
end
```

Why will the following lines returns no output?

```
    puts @log_in_page.error_message
    puts @log_in_page.get_error_message
```

Can you please help me?

Thanks.

Comment: It would help if you could (1) give enough page's code (eg html) to reproduce the problem or a link to the actual page being tested and (2) if you could simplify your code to be the minimum required to reproduce the problem (eg the teardown method is not relevant). The more direct the question and easier it is for us to reproduce, the easier it is to give an answer without guessing or making assumptions.

Comment: Hi Justin, sorry about that, I have simplified the example. Please let me know if it still does not make sense.

Comment: Can you share the html of the error message, including the styles? Given that you get no text (which I assume you mean by no output), it likely means that the element's text is not visible (perhaps a timing issue or a styling issue).

Comment: http://eric-lin.net/files/Internet%20Banking%20for%20Business%20Login.htm, the error message I am trying to locate is "There were 3 errors on the page.", thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that there is a timing issue due to the error message being displayed through javascript. It is likely that the error message element is always in the html of the page, but when login fails, the error message element's style is changed to be something visible.

When a page object (or watir) element returns its text, it only includes the visible text. So if the error message is not yet visible, you get no text.

Try waiting to ensure the element is visible to the user:

```
def get_error_message
  error_message_element.when_present.text
end
```

`when_present` will wait up to 5 seconds for the element to become visible to the user and then return the text.

**Update** - Multiple h3s:

It looks like the actual problem is that there are multiple h3 elements that have that class. Watir always returns the first match, which in this case is the cookie error heading. Given that it is not being displayed, you get the blank text.

The solution would be to reduce the search scope so that you the first h3 is the one you want. This can be done by only looking in the error message list. I would define the page object as follows. Note that you do not need to specify the class of the h3 element since it is the only h3 element in the list.

```
class LogIn
  include PageObject

  div(:error_message_list, :id => 'errorMessageList')
  h3(:error_message){ error_message_list_element.h3_element }
end
```

This will then find the right h3 element:

```
browser = Watir::Browser.new
browser.goto 'https://www.bnz.co.nz/ib4b/app/login'
browser.button(:text => 'Login').click

page = LogIn.new(browser)
page.error_message
#=> "There were 3 errors on the page."
```

Comment: Hi Justin. I changed it and it still ran with error "===============================================================================
Error: test_failed_log_in(TestLogIn)
  Watir::Wait::TimeoutError: timed out after 5 seconds, waiting for {:class=>"no-margin white-text", :tag_name=>"h3"} to become present"

Comment: In your question you said "returns no output" and here you say "still ran with error". Can you please clarify if in your original question you were seeing an error or no text?

Comment: Previously when the mothod is
 def get_error_message
    self.error_message
  end
It returns no output.

When it is 
def get_error_message
  error_message_element.when_present.text
end

It ran with error because it can't wait for this error_message_element to be present after 5 seconds, for some reason it can't locate this element at all.

Comment: At the end of the log_in method it calls AccountSummary.new(@browser), will that be the reason? I tried with this line removed and it is not working still.

Comment: I found the page that I think you are testing. The problem is that there are multiple matching h3 elements. I have updated the answer to address this.